# Assets and subfolders

Tags: assets

I'm using Assets 2.0.4 and I just noticed that it doesn't include my subfolders that exist within my upload directories from when I had Assets 1.  For instance, I have a press releases folder that has about 8-10 subfolders in it, but all I see in Assets 2 is the parent directory.  Is this a bug?

If not, how would I get all of my subfolders indexed in Assets without having to re-upload them all?

System: EE 2.5.5 / Assets 2.0.4 / PHP 5.2.

Comment: Did you update your indexes after installing Assets 2?

Comment: Yes, I did.  That was the first thing I did.

Comment: Does Assets 2 require PHP 5.3?  Would upgrading that make any difference?

Comment: Hey Mitchell - can you add a screenshot of your file upload preference, as well as the directory layout via FTP?  Also, does upgrading to 2.0.5 alleviate this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An update fixed the issue.  Thanks for the help, Lisa.